# Yii2 - Image upload and resizing,ajax upload support extension

Tags: yii2

Is there any good image uploading and resize extension for yii2; I don't want to use kartik because since I had a problem I've not gotten any help to understand where the problem is, same situation with Illustrated behavior so I am stack in my project.

What I want is multiple image uploading,ajax support(even for old browser if not to turn to normal file input), image resizing keeping good quality,allowing one image to be saved in different sizes and Preview the file when selected from client side(not obliged).

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use image magick direcly.

Check if these two functions can be useful for you:

```
public static function generateImagesScaledAndCropped($inputFile, $outputFile, $params)
{
    $imageMagickConvert = \Yii::$app->params['imagick.convert'];
    $cmd = sprintf("%s %s -resize %dx%d^ -gravity Center -crop %dx%d+0+0 %s", $imageMagickConvert, $inputFile, $params['edge'], $params['edge'], $params['edge'], $params['edge'], $outputFile);
    exec($cmd);
}
public static function generateImagesScaledByWidth($inputFile, $outputFile, $params)
{
    $imageMagickConvert = \Yii::$app->params['imagick.convert'];
    $cmd = sprintf("%s %s -resize %d %s", $imageMagickConvert, $inputFile, $params['width'], $outputFile);
    exec($cmd);
}
```

Params are:

```
<?php
return [
    'imagick.convert' => '/usr/bin/convert',
    'imagick.composite' => '/usr/bin/composite',    
];
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to reduce work efficiently, meaning I would like an extension because the come with their file input widget(client side support) and selected file preview

Answer (score 0):

I use Imagine as abstract layer on Imagine library which 
uses populars php libraries to work with images

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-imagine-index.html